# Create list from input using interact in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, io, functional-programming

I'm starting out with Haskell and was looking into I/O mechanims. I read up on the interact function which takes a function of type String -> String as parameter. I tried to write a simple program that takes to numbers from stdin and creates a list and prints it line by line.

```
import Data.List

readIn = sort . map read . words 
writeOut = unlines . map show
rangeList [n,m] = [n .. m] 
main = interact (writeOut . rangeList . readIn)
```

For some reason it wont print the numbers. Could you help me out?

Comment: Quick comment: since `rangeList` always has exactly two values as input, it’s probably better to use a 2-tuple `(n,m)` rather than a list, since a list should be able to have any number of values. As for the rest of the program, it looks absolutely fine at first glance; I’ll try running it now and see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

`interact` requires you to input an end-of-file (EOF) to stdin with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on Windows); when I type that combination, the output appears as required. This is necessary because, as the [documentation for `interact`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-15.1/base-4.13.0.0/Prelude.html#v:interact) states, ‘the entire input from the standard input device is passed to [interact] as its argument’; due to this, you need to explicitly signal the place where stdin ends.

(By the way, I’m not even sure how you got your program to compile; GHC gives me lots of ‘ambiguous type’ errors when I try. I had to add type signatures to get it working, at which point I found the solution above to work.)